# python sqlite question - Insert method

Tags: python, sqlite

In the code below `row` is a tuple of 200 elements (numbers) and `listOfVars` is a tuple of 200 strings that are variable names in the `testTable`. `tupleForm` is a list of tuples, 200 elements in each tuple.

The following code does not work. It returns a syntax error:

```
for row in tupleForm:
    cmd = '''INSERT INTO testTable listOfVars values row'''
    cur.execute(cmd)
```

However, the following works fine. Can someone explain why? I am finding sqlite so non-intuitive.

```
for row in tupleForm:
    cmd = '''INSERT INTO testTable %s values %s'''%(listOfVars, row) 
    cur.execute(cmd)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a table with 200 columns?  It is likely there's a better database design available to you.  For example, try putting what you currently have as most of your column names into a column of its own.

Comment: This is not SQLite's fault! SQLite has no way to know what `listOfVars` or `row` mean...

Comment: Try doing a `print(cmd)` after your `cmd = ...` assigments, and you'll see the difference in the 2. This isn't really a sqlite thing, it's simply a Python string formatting question. The best way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to apply Adam Bernier's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
insert_query = '''INSERT INTO testTable ({0}) VALUES ({1})'''.format(
               (','.join(listOfVars)), ','.join('?'*len(listOfVars)))
cur.executemany(insert_query, tupleForm)
```

Please do not use normal string interpolation for database queries.
We are fortunate to have [the DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) which explains in detail how to do what you require.

Edit:
A couple of quick reasons why this method is better than your 2nd attempt:

1. by using the built-in string-escaping tools we avoid SQL injection attacks, and
2. `executemany` accepts a list of tuples as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not tried it yet, since I do not completely understand it; though I can guess what the different commands are doing. Anyhow, appreciate the opportunity to learn new things. For the sake of understanding, why is this solution better than my second method, which works. I think SilentGhost has explained it, but I do not understand. I will accept the answer after I get a chance to try it out. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The first attempts to use the strings as the values, which is wrong. The second substitutes the string value of the tuples into the string, which results in `(...)` in both cases.

But both forms are incorrect, since the second doesn't escape values at all. What you *should* be doing is using a parametrized query.