# What is the optimized way to insert large number of records (more than 40,000) in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert more than 40,000 records into sqlite3 in one stretch.

What would be the best approach to insert them in least amount of time.

I have used prepared statements in Java and am aware that precompiled sql statements are faster as compared to raw sql queries. I was not able to find a code snippet for insert records using prepared statement inside sqlite3 using python. Any pointers in this direction would be appreciated.

I am even open to any other alternatives to prepared statements.

Thanks.

Comment: I would be interested in how faster it is to use executemany instead of the pure script way. Of course that doesn't count eventual sql injection with script way (executemany is safer).

Comment: Earlier with executescript, the time taken for 40,000 records was 8.3 minutes and with executemany it got reduced to 2.1 seconds.. Amazing performance for an embedded device with 128MB RAM and 1 GHz processor! May be this what you were interested in :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [executemany](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) with an appropriate iterator

Comment: I use an intermediate function which computes the insert query before executing it.. so what i am doing is concatinating these computed insert query and currently executing it with cursor.executescript(..) I don't know how can I user executemany() in this case?

Comment: The simplest way is to append your values in a list which is an iterator `cur.executemany("insert into characters(c,b) values (?,?)", [("c1","b1"),("c2","b2")])` it is not memory efficient but should cover your use case