# Python sqlite3 what happens if executemany() encounters an integrity error partway through?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, executemany

If I run the SQL command

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?);
```

with the constraint

```
CREATE my_table(
    user_name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Using sqlite3's `executemany()` command on a list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'h', 'i']`, I'm going to get a `sqlite3.IntegrityError`.

I have a few questions about the behavior of `executemany()` when it encounters this error, and I have been unable to find any documentation on the behavior.

1) Are the values inserted prior to the exception always intact?

2) Are there any cases in which values *after* the exception occurs might be inserted?

3) Is there any way to determine which value(s) cause an exception? (The best I can think of is to wrap the list in a generator to track the state, log the problem entries, and retry on the rest of the generator until the entire list is consumed.)

Answer (score 0):

The test script below provides some evidence:

1. The values inserted prior to the integrity constrain seem to be intact
2. The values to be inserted after the exception are not inserted
3. Not that I have found - I have used something similar to the solution you suggest.

Note that you can use a transaction if you want to prevent any values being inserted if an `IntegrityError` occurs.  Example below.  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055314/combine-inserts-into-one-transaction-python-sqlite3) for more.

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('del.db')
tuples = ('a','b','c','a','d')

conn.execute('create table test (col text primary key)')

conn.commit()
c = conn.cursor()
try:
    c.executemany('insert into test  values (?)', tuples)
except sqlite3.IntegrityError as exc:
    print(exc)

c.close()

results = conn.execute('select * from test')
results.fetchall()
```

results in the following output

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: test.col
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',)]
```

Whereas if you use a transaction:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('begin')
try:
    c.executemany('insert into test  values (?)', tuples)
except sqlite3.IntegrityError as exc:
    c.execute('rollback')
```

No data is entered.